# App store submission error related to launch Images

Tags: ios, xcode

I know we have lots of post for this type of error,But nothing will work for me,I have uploaded other 4 apps successfully without any issue but one app I am facing issue (attached Images),Any one have appropriate step for resolve this error. Kind for your help and positive response.After lots of try I am posting this question sorry guys if you have the info that will be helpful for me.

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image/ listout the sizes of images used in the 'LaunchImage' inside your 'XCAssets'

Comment: give list of your all launchimage size and your launchimage extension(png or other).

Comment: I used png images and used below size 640 , 960,
    640 ,1136
    750 ,1334
   1242,2208
   2208,1242

Answer (score 0):

your launch image must be 1136*640 and 960*640 
image default@2x.png and default.png use in this 
i think help it for you

Comment: No, I did all this and try with all the sizes but nothing seems to be work